# What does the "[r #]" value in Nikon viewfinders and displays mean?

Tags: nikon, viewfinder, camera-controls, nikon-d5500

I've been struggling to find any reference to this in the manual for the D5500. Presumably once I know what it's even called it will be easier to research.

On the right in the viewfinder, and also in Camera Control Pro 2 (easier to screenshot) is a bracketed 'r' with a number, e.g. `[r  2]`, highlighted in red below:

[image]

Could someone please tell me what it does, or at least what it's called, so I can look it up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the number of shots remaining (hence the "r") that you can take and store on your card.

When you half-press the shutter button, the number changes to the number of shots remaining in your memory buffer (pictures stored in memory that haven't been written to the storage card yet). This lets you know how many more shots you can take in "C<sub>H</sub>" (continuous high-speed) shooting mode.

If your card is large enough to hold over 999 images (such as shooting only in JPEG mode, especially at smaller image size), the "r" will disappear because the remaining count needs 4 digits to display.

Comment: Is it the capacity remaining in the card? Or the capacity remaining in the buffer? With EOS cameras the number on the same location is the buffer capacity remaining. The card capacity is displayed on the top of camera LCD.

Comment: @MichaelClark On Nikons, at least as of last year's models, it's modal. The brackets show the remaining card capacity, _until_ you half-press the shutter, in which case it shows the remaining buffer capacity.

Comment: @MichaelClark in viewfinder mode looking through the viewfinder, it's as I described. It's the same on the top LCD as well, if brackets are shown. On my D800E, I have that location set to show ISO on the top LCD, but when I half-press the shutter, that section changes to show buffer remaining.

Comment: @MichaelClark in live view, the brackets are as I described, showing shots remaining on the card by default, and remaining in buffer with the shutter half-pressed.

Comment: Thank you. Simple, once you know;) I hadn't equated the shutter button half-press with the changing data display, & as mentioned in my other comment to @Caleb skimming the manual wasn't finding 'r something' just a generic 88.8

Comment: @Tetsujin =) I found that I learned my camera best by just going through the user manual front to back, without skipping anything, camera in hand, while on a cross-country flight. I did this a few times when I was traveling heavy for work, and learned a lot about how to operate my camera and set it up how I like it.

Answer (score 8):

> Could someone please tell me what it does, or at least what it's called, so I can look it up?

Scottbb's answer is correct and you should accept it, but I wanted to follow up with a little more information about how to find the answer in case you have others like it.

There's a diagram on page 6 of the [Nikon D5500 user manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/S7Fu200SBsmL02ANPHv57tH29i55/D5500UM_SG(En)03.pdf) (PDF) that describes the different parts of the viewfinder display, including this detail:

[image: Nikon viewfinder data display]

This is a detail that shows every segment of the display all at once, so I can see how you might not immediately notice that it includes the `[r 2]` part that you're asking about. But if you look in the place in this detail where the `[r 2]` message appears in your camera, you'll see `[88.8]` called out as item 13, and that item is described in the text below:

```
Number of exposures remaining.......................................31
Number of shots remaining before memory buffer fills.............37
White balance recording indicator Exposure compensation value....72 
Flash compensation value ..........12
ISO sensitivity.................................12
Capture mode indicator
```

So this part of the display actually serves six different purposes. They're not described in all that much detail on their respective pages, but I think it's enough. Page 31 again shows the corresponding part of the rear display (which also uses the bracket notation) and calls it "number of exposures remaining," including the helpful detail that a K is displayed as a 1000's multiplier if you have more than 1000 exposures left. Page 37 shows the viewfinder display that you see when you half-press the shutter release button, and labels the bracket area (this time including the 'r') as "buffer capacity."

The [D5500 reference manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/ETOYI00bfdW602XchPU57r5bLc70/D5500RM_(En)03.pdf) (PDF) contains similar diagrams with page references, and has a more detailed description of the buffer size indicator on page 73:

> **Buffer Size:** The approximate number of images that can be stored in the memory buffer at current settings is shown in the viewfinder
>   exposure-count display while the shutter-release button is pressed.

So the information you need is in the manual, it's just a little hard to recognize in that initial diagram.

Comment: Except instead of the User manual, the D5500 Reference manual is much more complete.  Free at http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/196/D5500.html

Comment: @WayneF That's usually how it goes with user manuals and reference manuals -- the former for people who want to know what they need to know, the latter for cases where you want to know *everything*. That's why I linked to both.

Comment: Thank you. I had actually seen that in the manual [I already have both versions] but couldn't equate it to what I was trying to find. I'd been skimming to find some actual picture of 'r something' & didn't equate it with the 88.8

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this on my nikon d7500 as well. It says 2.1k in brackets, press the shutter halfway and it changes to r29. Do I have 29 left, or 2.1k? I'm not familiar with buffering,etc..but after I'm done and transfer my pictures, I delete everything on my card. So, I guess what exactly do I do?

Comment: Hi Jenny. If you have a new question, please post a brand new question. Also, do ensure that your question is clear. It's not clear to me what problem you're encountering or what exactly you are asking about here. If you want to know what a buffer is, ask that. If you want to know what to do, well, you'll have to narrow that down a bit to exactly some functionality or something.

Comment: I think what is being asked is clear and is related to the present question - what does 2.1k mean, since it appears to not be consistent with r29.

Comment: @Not_Einstein it doesn't matter - questions should not be posted as answers.

Comment: This should really just be a comment under Scotbb's answer, if anything - because his answer quite clearly explains this very thing.