# Olympus OM-D E-M1 Mark III: Is there a way to get the number of shots left in continuous shooting before the buffer fills?

Tags: performance, olympus-omd, continuous-drive

Many interchangeable-lens cameras provide some sort of buffer capacity display when shooting, typically indicating the approximate remaining number of images that can be stored in the buffer, and hence how many more pictures can be taken in continuous shooting mode before the camera slows down:

- [Canon DSLRs display a number (like `9` or `50`) in the bottom right corner of the viewfinder display](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART104912&cat=1234B&actp=LIST) indicating the approximate number of shots left.

  - In Live View, and on Canon mirrorless system cameras, this value is displayed in the top left of the display, immediately to the right of the number in brackets indicating the remaining memory card capacity, e.g. `[3000] 20` means the memory card can hold about more 3000 shots, and there is space for about 20 images in the buffer.
- [Nikon DSLR and Z Series cameras will show a value like `r50` when the shutter button is half-pressed](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/ni/NI_article?articleNo=000001583&lang=en_US), indicating the remaining buffer capacity. **See also: [What does the "[r #]" value in Nikon viewfinders and displays mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85343)**
- Newer Panasonic mirrorless system cameras (both Micro Four Thirds and L-mount) display the remaining buffer capacity in essentially the same manner as Nikon cameras.
- [Sony cameras have a feature called "Cont. Shoot. Length"](https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1650/v1/en/contents/TP0001491328.html), where a bar on the left side of the screen visually shows the remaining buffer capacity. When this bar becomes empty and the word "SLOW" is displayed, the buffer is full.

However, I cannot find a similar feature on my Olympus OM-D E-M1 Mark III. Does such a feature exist in the camera? If so, where might I be able to enable it? I've already reached out to Olympus, [including on Twitter](https://twitter.com/bwDraco/status/1241950510741159936), about a buffer capacity display feature.

Comment: Not an answer, but the Olympus OMD cameras Facebook page has a lot of knowledgeable users on. https://www.facebook.com/groups/em1II Might be worth asking in there if you're a Facebook user.

Comment: In addition, I use a 150MB/s class 3 card with my 10.3, and in high-speed continuous, I've not reached a buffer limit. it just keeps going until the card is full, but after about 10 shots the rate drops to around 1 shot/second.